# How to horizontal/Vertical scroll a panoramic image in Android?

Tags: android, image, view, scroll, camera

I'm looking for to some way for make a scroll, or scan of a panoramic image in Android. With this I mean show a part of my image adjusting the height of the image (or width in vertical) and automatically moving slowly the view scrolling all the image. For example:

[image]

this image its so big to try to see it in a 16:9 device(with a bit of detail i mean), so i want to do something like:

[image]

Just show that part in the screen and move it slowly to the right till the end of the image. Achieving a "scroll" effect across the image.

I have been looking in the website and internet last days and I just found the library of PanoramicGL or some ways to watch 360º images.

Comment: Did you tried `HorizontalScrollView` nested inside a `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Is For **Scroll** [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960701/android-repeat-scrolling-panoramic-photo-seamlessly-across-background)

You must use PanoramaClient (which is part of [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)) to open [PhotoSphere](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html) photos.

An example of how to do this can be found on this Android developer blog post:

```
// This listener will be called with information about the given panorama.
OnPanoramaInfoLoadedListener infoLoadedListener =
new OnPanoramaInfoLoadedListener() {
@Override
public void onPanoramaInfoLoaded(ConnectionResult result,
                                 Intent viewerIntent) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // If the intent is not null, the image can be shown as a
        // panorama.
        if (viewerIntent != null) {
            // Use the given intent to start the panorama viewer.
            startActivity(viewerIntent);
        }
    }

    // If viewerIntent is null, the image is not a viewable panorama.
 }
 };
 // Create client instance and connect to it.
 PanoramaClient client = ...
 ...
 // Once connected to the client, initiate the asynchronous check on whether
 //the image is a viewable panorama.
 client.loadPanoramaInfo(infoLoadedListener, panoramaUri);
```

Comment: if you think my answer is useful then vote it as favourite answer so others can use it..

Comment: Done it, also vote my solution. The final method that i did can help too a lot of users

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kishu, I made my own method to animate a panoramic image dynamically depending if its in landscape or portrait mode.

You can ignore the orientation value of the method, I only use it to change the animation of the video from X to Y if I want to see the image in landscape.

```
 public void animatePanorama(int orientation) {

    int duration;
    // The milisecons that we will use dinamically for the animation, been this is 1,31milisecons for pixel
    float miliseconsPixel = 1.31f;
    float imageWidth;

    //Delta X and Y values for the animation
    float deltaX = 0f;
    float deltaY = 0f;
    float aspectRatio;
    //We get the drawable from the container to calcule his real Width and Height
    final Drawable d = mImageContainer.getDrawable();
    final int origWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int origHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
    //With that we get the real aspect ratio and a duration

    if (origWidth > origHeight) {
        aspectRatio = (float) origWidth / (float) origHeight;
        duration = (int) (miliseconsPixel * origWidth);
        imageWidth = mImageContainer.getMeasuredHeight() * aspectRatio;
    } else {
        aspectRatio = (float) origHeight / (float) origWidth;
        duration = (int) (miliseconsPixel * origHeight);
        imageWidth = mImageContainer.getMeasuredWidth() * aspectRatio;
    }

    //Set if the animation will be horizontal(Portrait) or Vertical(landscape)
    if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 180)
        deltaX = imageWidth / 2f - mImageContainer.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    else
        deltaY = imageWidth / 2f - mImageContainer.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

    //New Animation
    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(deltaX, -deltaX, deltaY, -deltaY);
    //Add Duration
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    //Add cycle for repeating mode
    animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mImageContainer.startAnimation(animation);
}
```